How to update an Android app with Bluetooth for API 33
I need to make compatible with Android API 33, an app that contains a slightly modified version of the class "BluetoothLeService.java" (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/browseable/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.java).
The app works fine with devices based on older Android versions, but not from API 33 onwards.
Unfortunately, many GATT server connection examples are outdated and do not take into account newer versions of Android.
I made 2 tests with Android 8.0 (API 26) and with Android 14 (API 34) and in the log I found some differences in the connection to the GATT server.

Smartphone with Android 8.0 (API 26):
discoverServices() - device: 34:15:13:1C:AE:E0
onConnectionUpdated() - Device=34:15:13:1C:AE:E0 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
onSearchComplete() = Device=34:15:13:1C:AE:E0 Status=0
onConnectionUpdated() - Device=34:15:13:1C:AE:E0 interval=39 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
characteristic.getUuid(): 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
characteristicTX = 0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb:android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@1970e7e
characteristicRX = 0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb:android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@1970e7e
Connected -> characteristicTX = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@1970e7e
Connected -> characteristicRX = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@1970e7e

Smartphone with Android 14 (API 34):
discoverServices() - device: XX:XX:XX:XX:AE:E0
onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:AE:E0 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
onSearchComplete() = Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:AE:E0 Status=0
onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:AE:E0 interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
No other data!


Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Google has created a guide that also documents the changes and how your own applications need to be adapted.

I solved it.
The problem was not with the BluetoothLeService class but with a field in the 'registerReceiver' method.
Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED blocks access to BroadcastReceiver, instead the Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED field should be used.
The documentation at
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/ble/connect-gatt-server?hl=en#java
is out of date and does not address this issue.
